# Can I edit the TextBody of EmailMessage object when registering a case from Email-to-Case?

Tags: apex, trigger, case, email2case, emailmessage

Can I write a 'after insert' trigger on EmailMessage object to edit the TextBody of incoming Mail?
Is it possible in Salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

The [EmailMessage object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm?search_text=emailtemplate) permits the `TextBody` field to be updated if the status = `Draft` and other conditions as shown below

> update() is supported when an email record is in Draft status, and IsPrivateDraft is false. It’s also supported if the email status is Draft, IsPrivateDraft is true, and CreatedBy is associated with the current user. When the email record isn’t in Draft status, the IsExternallyVisible field and custom fields only can be updated.

Triggers can certainly be written on `EmailMessage` including afterInsert triggers.

Note that some fields on `EmailMessage` can't be updated like `Incoming` and `ParentId` (the case it is associated to). See [the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm?search_text=emailtemplate)

Comment: Hi Eric, I wrote a trigger to copy `TextBody` from `EmailMessage` to a custom object. But I see that only the text of default template was copied and not the actual body which was sent as part of the body.